# How can I authenticate Azure Repos on my Self-hosted VM to install Node.js package with npm?

Tags: azure, npm, npm-install, azure-repos, npm-build

I have a Node.js package in my Azure DevOps Repository.
I want to install the package using `npm install` and `npm run build`.
It runs locally on VS Code without any errors, but I am not able to execute the same on an Azure Self-hosted VM.

The error I get is:

> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/Truboard-Tech/TruGreen/_git/TruboardMantineComponents/'

I am able to clone the same repo on my Azure VM.

Is there a way I need to authenticate with my Azure Repos on VM?